# getting id from user table using $_SESSION

Tags: php, sql

I have a simple login and when user is logged they can upload a title and comment (and also an image but we can ignore this as this works ok) to a database. What I want is the user id of the person currently logged in to be inserted into the database as well. This is my current code

login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["user"])){
    header("location:index.php");
    exit();
}

?>

<?php

if(isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])){
    // Filter everything except letters and numbers
    $user = preg_replace('#^A-Za-z0-9#i','',$_POST["username"]);
    $password = preg_replace('#^A-Za-z0-9#i','',$_POST["password"]);

    // Connect to mySQL
    include"assets/scripts/sql_connect.php";

    // Query the person
    $sql = $conn->query("SELECT id FROM user_login WHERE user_name='$user' AND user_password='$password' LIMIT 1");

    // Make sure person exists
    $existCount = $sql->rowCount();

    // Evaluate the count
    if($existCount == 1){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            $id = $row["id"];
        }
        $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
        $_SESSION["user"] = $user;
        $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
        header("location:index.php");
        exit();
    }else{
        echo"Login details incorrect, try again <a href='index.php'>Click here</a>";
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
session_start();

include"assets/scripts/sql_connect.php";

if (isset($_POST['image_title'])){

    $userid =  $_SESSION["id"];
    $image_title = $_POST['image_title'];
    $image_comment = $_POST['image_comment'];


    //Add image text to the database
    $sql = $conn->query("INSERT INTO user_image(user_id,image_title,image_comment, image_date_added) VALUES('$userid','$image_title','$image_comment', now())") or die(mysql_error());
    $id = $conn->lastInsertId();

    $image_id = $conn->lastInsertID();  
    // Places image in the images folder
    $new_name = "$image_id.jpg";
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['app_art_image']['tmp_name'],"appArtImages/$new_name");
    header("location:gallery.php");
    exit();
}       
?>
```

The problem i get is that 0 gets inserted into the user_id field in the user_image database no matter what user is logged in.

Comment: if you do `echo $id` just after the sql query, is it printing something?

Comment: No it prints nothing.

Comment: So it's a problem of sql query and not from session. Please check before making sql query if `$user`  and `$password` are good as you wanted

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean 'as good as you wanted'.

Comment: What I want to mean is echo theses variables and see if they are good or if there's a problem ( if they doesn't equal what you have sent)

Comment: Yes I can echo both, eg <?php echo $_SESSION["user"]; ?> and it will print the username of the user currently logged in.

Answer (score 1):

use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysql_fetch_array()`
try

```
 if($existCount == 1){
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
                $id = $row["id"];
                $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                break;
            }
            $_SESSION["user"] = $user;
            $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
            header("location:index.php");
            exit();
        }else{
            echo"Login details incorrect, try again <a href='index.php'>Click here</a>";
            exit();
        }
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: I already had session_start in my login.php. Sorry should have included that in my original post as well. I have edited my original post to reflect this.

Comment: echo $_SESSION["id"] to check its value before insert query and tell me. I might help.

Comment: It doesn't echo anything at all. I can echo <?php echo $_SESSION["user"];  ?>  and it will show the username of the user currently logged but <?php echo $_SESSION["id"];  ?> gives nothing. Its blank.

Comment: If I do <?php echo $_SESSION["id"]; ?>  after your edit I get Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp..... error.

Comment: it means that  $_SESSION["id"] = $id; is not executing. try  print_r($row) before  in my code. if nothing print that means while loop is not  executing

Comment: try the edited code . the problem is mysql_fetch_array() returns array not associative array

Comment: I made the changes. I still get the same error message but this time the number 1 is printed below it.

Answer (score 1):

Manged to solve it. I changed

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
```

in login.php to

```
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
```